# ID of DOM element gets set but can't mounted on

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I want to implement a component which sets the ID of a particular element in the DOM tree dynamically, given `@Input` parameter.

Using a client library, in particular the Stripe Client (stripe.js), I want to mount more complex components on that said element like this:

```
@ViewChild('elementRef', {read: ElementRef}) elementRef: ElementRef;

// ..

get elementId() {
  return this.type ? this.type + '-element' : null;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.id = this.elementId;
  this._cd.detectChanges();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this._element = this._stripeClientService.elements.create(this.type, this.options);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(document.getElementById(this.elementId));
    this._element.mount(this.elementId);
  }, 100);


  this._element.on('change', (event) => {
    const displayError = document.getElementById('errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      this.canSubmit = false;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
      this.canSubmit = true;
    }
  });
}
```

The problem: Even though I use `setTimout()` (should not be necessary imho), call `detectChanges()`, *and* try to initialize the component in `ngAfterViewInit()`, I am still getting this:

```
ERROR IntegrationError: The selector you specified (iban-element) applies to no DOM elements that are currently on the page. Make sure the element exists on the page before calling mount().
    at new t (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:11502)
    at t.<anonymous> (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:97045)
    at t.mount (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:25699)
```

**However*, I do see this as well, coming from `console.log(document.getElementById(this.elementId));`, in the console:

```xml
<div _ng-content-c29 id="card-element"></div>
```

So that's that ..

I am not sure what other options I am having here.

Comment: The command is looking for an element with the id `iban-element`. You could put `console.log("type", this.type)` in the `elementId` getter, to see if the element type is always what you expect.

Comment: @ConnorsFan That's why I have `console.log(document.getElementById(this.elementId));` in `ngAfterViewInit`. I was not able  to make this work by referencing the ID of the element, but, as stated in the answer below, it worked by passing in the native element.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know why it did not work with a `string`. I was able to do it before when I had separate components and put in `card` or `iban` separately. However, this does not seem to work in a dynamic environment.

But what *does* work is this apparently:

```
this._element.mount(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
```

I just passed in the `nativeElement` and apparently the API can work with that too.